# Create an array function within a class in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have spent hours trying to find a solution but can't find any. Apologies - novice here.

I want to add addCrewMember function in RocketShip class that will allow me to add new members to the crewMembers array.

I know that I should use append method but it keeps giving me error. Thoughts?

```
class RocketShip
{
    var speed: Double
    let modelNumber: Int
    let shipName : String

    var crewMembers: Array<String>

    init (name: String, number: Int)
    {
        shipName = name
        modelNumber = number

        speed = 0.0

        crewMembers = ["John", "Jane"]
    }

    func addSpeed(addedSpeed: Double)-> Double
    {
        speed = speed + addedSpeed

        return speed
    }

    func addBoostedSpeed(addedSpeed: Double, numberOfBoosts: Int) -> Double
    {
        let boostedSpeed = addedSpeed * Double (numberOfBoosts)

        speed = speed + boostedSpeed

        return speed
    }
    func addCrewMembers(addCrewMembers: String) -> STring
    {    
         addCrewMembers = crewMembers.append()
         return crewMembers
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't included your `addCrewMember` code or the error you're getting, so it's a bit hard for anybody to help. If I code my own, it works fine.

Comment: Oh I added the function

Comment: Use CMD-K to format your code. It makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
func addCrewMembers(newMember: String) -> [String]
{    
    crewMembers.append(newMember)
    return crewMembers
}
```

Comment: Read the *A Swift Tour* and the first few chapters in the Swift Language Guide to learn the basics.